# Synchronizing the performance of two algorithms to that of the slowest bottleneck

Tags: c#, performance, queue

I have two methods. One method that retrieves some data, and another that processes that data. 
Both algorithms operate at a different speed so I want to synchronize the performance of both algorithms so that they run at the speed of the bottleneck. I was thinking of using a message queue of a maximum size. Until  the queue has reached it's maximum size, the retrieval method carries on populating the list whilst the processing method removes items from the list on a different thread for as long as there are items on the list. If list reaches its maximum size then it will wait until the queue is no longer at its maximum size.

Does that sound like the most logical approach?

I was thinking of some form of generic class something along the lines of

```
Queue<T> _theQueue;
private int _maxQueueSize;

Func<T> _processor;
Func<T> _populator;

ChasedQueue(Func<T> processor, Funct<T> populator, int maxQueueSize = 30)
{
    _theQueue = new Queue<T>();
    _maxQueueSize =
    _processor = processor;
    _populator = populator;
}

public void Start()
{
    new Thread(() => StartChaser()).Start();
    new Thread(() => StartPopulator()).Start();
}

private void StartChaser()
{
    while ((element = _documentQueue.poll) != null) 
    {
        _processor(_documentQueue.Dequeue());
    } 
}   

private void StartPopulator()
{
    foreach(var item in _populator)
    {
        while(_theQueue.Count < _maxQueueSize)
        {
            _documentQueue.Enqueue(item);
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: ReactiveExtensions, namely [Zip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reactive.linq.observable.zip%28v=vs.103%29.aspx), seems like a good fit [[example here](http://www.introtorx.com/content/v1.0.10621.0/12_CombiningSequences.html)]. Your two algorithms would just expose their streaming results as observables that you could zip...

Comment: @Patryk Ćwiek: It's worth putting your comment as an answer I think, so that the question can be closed.

Comment: @Jamie: Make sure to accept the provided answer if it was indeed helpful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Promoting my comment to a fully-fledged answer, for completeness:

ReactiveExtensions, namely [Zip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reactive.linq.observable.zip%28v=vs.103%29.aspx), seems like a good fit [[example here]‌](http://www.introtorx.com/content/v1.0.10621.0/12_CombiningSequences.html#Zip)​. Your two algorithms would just expose their streaming results as observables that you could zip...